# How to determine top level template file in functions.php?

Tags: template-hierarchy

I am using `index.php` for my home page, and I am using `single.php` for my single post page. In my `functions.php` how can I determine if I am in `index.php` or `single.php`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to check which _template file_ has been loaded, as opposed to what _type_ the current query is?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the single page by using is_single() function.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

As for index page, I am not 100% sure but is_home() may be the one.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Answer (score -1):

There is no 'standard' way of doing this, because different themes can load templates differently. You can access the global $pagename and make a conditional. i.e.:

```
global $pagename;
echo $pagename;
```